# What should I do if I find answer on my own question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, self-answer

So, suppose I posted a question, then some time passed, and then I by my own found answer to this question. What should I do in this situation? Close question, post an answer, or what?

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, post the solution as the answer to your question.  This way, when others stumble across the same problem, they don't have to wait for someone to answer a question they post, but instead, they can find your question & answer in a search result.

An exception to this rule *might* be made if the actual solution is based on some silly oversight.  For example if you were having trouble getting your perfectly fine looking Java code to compile and the solution ended up being that you were trying to compile it as C... well this can probably just be deleted.  If you were missing a single closing parenthesis or brace, or misspelled the name of something, this might also just be deleted.

It just kind of depends.  But if you think there's any remote possibility that someone else might run into a similar enough problem that an existing question-and-answer would be useful to them, post your answer.